# How to uninstall default nginx on openBSD

Tags: nginx, openbsd, uninstall

I want to install a custom compiled nginx on OpenBSD, but I'm having problems running it because nginx is already installed in the default OpenBSD (5.6) install.

In some way it is like I managed to mix files and configurations from the two, but the main program is the original from the OS installation.

I've compiled and installed nginx with the aid of this two instructions: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#Installation_for_NGINX and http://wiki.nginx.org/OnOpenBSD

I've tried with pkg_delete with no results. Also googled to no avail.

How can I remove it before installing my version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird because since 5.6 [Nginx was moved from the base OS to ports](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/current.html#20140826b).

But anyway, these are the files associated with Nginx that should be removed:

```
rm -f /etc/rc.d/nginx
rm -f /usr/sbin/nginx
rm -f /usr/share/man/man8/nginx.8
rm -f /usr/share/man/man5/nginx.conf.5
```

You may also want to make sure to remove traces of nginx in the rc.d.